# How to Build Raw Transaction Data

Tags: web3js, nodejs, typescript

I only have the source address, the destination address and the amount of money to send.

Can I create offline-signed raw transaction data from this information?

Also, I want to do something like that with Nodejs, JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

yes, in web3.js, you can do it using these packages:

- [ethereumjs-tx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ethereumjs/tx)
- [ethereumjs-common](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ethereumjs/common)

Here is an example using web3.js:

```js
const Web3 = require("web3");
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction;
const Common = require('ethereumjs-common').default;

const NODE_URL = "CHAINSTACK_NODE_URL";
const web3 = new Web3(NODE_URL);

async function sendEth(value) {

    // Define the sender and receiver addresses, and the private key
    const sender = '0x19e7e376e7c213b7e7e7e46cc70a5dd086daff2a';
    const receiver = '0xe9ba4b4d84d7a3c80245514213b88d50ed937114';
    const privateKey = Buffer.from('1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111', 'hex');

    // Define the gas limit
    const gasLimit = await web3.eth.estimateGas({
        from: sender,
        to: receiver,
    });

    // Get the transaction count for the sender address
    const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(sender);

    // Define the transaction object
    const transactionObject = {
        to: receiver,
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('50', 'gwei')),
        gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(gasLimit),
        nonce: web3.utils.toHex(nonce),
        value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei(value, 'ether')),
    };

    // Define the chain configuration
    const common = Common.forCustomChain(
      'mainnet', {
          name: 'sepolia',
          networkId: 11155111,
          chainId: 11155111,
      },
      'petersburg',
  );

    // Create a new transaction object to sign 
    const tx = new Tx(transactionObject, {
        common
    });

    // Sign the transaction using the private key  
    const signedTx = tx.sign(privateKey);

    // Serialize the signed transaction and send it to the blockchain 
    const serializedTx = tx.serialize();
    const rawTransaction = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex');
    console.log(`Raw transaction: ${rawTransaction}\n`)
}

sendEth("2");
```

You will need to edit `CHAINSTACK_NODE_URL` with your own RPC endpoint and the addresses and private key.

When you run it, it will log the serialized signed transaction. You only need to send it using `sendSignedTransaction`.

```sh
Raw transaction: 0xf86f20850ba43b740082520894f25dadf841518a2cb516307876ce44f416661085881bc16d674ec800008083027125a0d912cc7da45d4b1244bdf93fb7ed48d997ff279809e2edcadbf8404ae92b9687a01e1f18a934e1fabed7fc010f9a56888fa1f5d0e9b9f0a6330348f34ff40d8c19
```

> You can find the complete example and explanation in the [Chainstack docs | eth_sendRawTransaction](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/ethereum-sendrawtransaction)

Comment: Thank you for explaining so politely!

I have general knowledge of Nodejs, but absolutely no knowledge of BlockChain or ETH.

How do I get Web3js to work?
I searched, but Geth and others are too difficult for me to understand.

Comment: No problem! Yes, you need Nodejs and the web3.js library. Then you just create a new js file and paste the code in it. Here you can find the steps needed:

https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/web3-libraries

You also need an RPC endpoint to place in const NODE_URL, you can get one for free at Chainstack if you need one :) 

https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/ethereum-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Refer these for more info. 
https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/transactions/ 
https://goethereumbook.org/transaction-raw-create/